# CakePHP SQL Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, prepared-statement

I've finally gotten jQuery AutoComplete to work with CakePHP. My initial plan was to have a grouped/categorised list, if the user enters the name of the school it will display all of that school's shows and if they enter the name of the show it will show the school that it is from.

I found this very hard to get implemented using Cake syntax so I decided to concatenate the name of the school and the name of the show and then compare that string to the $term. I realised VirtualFields would not work across multiple models so adopted using prepared statements, the syntax itself evaluated fine but I get this SQL error:

```
"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'romeo and juliet' in 'where clause'"
```

So it seems to pass the term fine but compares it to the column name rather than the record. Here is the syntax for my AutoComplete function with the prepared statement:

```
 public function autoComplete() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $term = $_GET['term'];
    $shownames = $this->Order->Show->query(
        'SELECT CONCAT(sm_schools.title, " - ", sm_shows.title)
        FROM sm_shows
        LEFT JOIN sm_schools
        ON sm_shows.school_id = sm_schools.id
        WHERE CONCAT(sm_schools.title, " - ", sm_shows.title) LIKE ' .$term
    );
    echo json_encode($this->_encode($shownames));
}
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: The code you posted is not a prepared statement.  See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements What you are using is vulnerable to SQL injection.  What is the MySQL query that is generated when you see that error?

Comment: Here is the query that's generated (apologies for the terrible formatting)

SQL Query: SELECT CONCAT(sm_schools.title, " - ", sm_shows.title)FROM sm_showsLEFT JOIN sm_schoolsON sm_shows.school_id = sm_schools.idWHERE CONCAT(sm_schools.title, " - ", sm_shows.title) LIKE Romeo and Juliet

Answer (score 2):

There's no quotes around Romeo and Juliet, which is probably where the error is coming from.  However, you should be doing this with actual prepared statements.

```
$db = $this->Order->getDataSource();
$shownames = $db->fetchAll(
    'SELECT CONCAT(sm_schools.title, " - ", sm_shows.title)
    FROM sm_shows
    LEFT JOIN sm_schools
    ON sm_shows.school_id = sm_schools.id
    WHERE CONCAT(sm_schools.title, " - ", sm_shows.title) LIKE ?',
    array($term)
);
```

Comment: Apologies, I've been off the radar for a few weeks! I tried the code you provided which didn't result in any SQL errors but just returns an empty set. I'm starting to think this isn't going to be possible using prepared statements? I've reverted to using Cake syntax to pull the data, but I'm really struggling to get a grouped select field.

Comment: correct answer. Although I always find counter intuitive the "fetchAll" method name, might be more generic since it can be used for multiple purposes (insert, update, etc)